# How to roll back the transaction when run time exception occurred

Tags: java, transactions, ejb

I have two table and want both table must update and save altogether otherwise rollback. i am using Transaction but not getting expected result when found runtime exception. Table_1 got updated and table_2 was not updated after getting some conversion issues in my java code.

```
    Service Class

    public void startTransaction(){
    try{
      transaction.begin();
      //Calls manager's class method to update and save the data into table
     transaction.commit();
    }catch(Exceptio e){
      transaction.rollback();
    }

}
```

**Manager class**

```
public void updateAndSave(){

try{
 -> calls DAO method for table_1 
   ->Update Table_1 via DAO update method
-> calls DAO method for table_2   
  ->Update Table_2 via DAO update method

}catch(Exception e){
......
}

}
```

Comment: Are "Service Class" and "Manager class" EJBs, and if so, what kind?  How is the updateAndSave() method called? Can you show actually code rather than just a comment? Is it invoked via an injected EJB reference?